# Using Python to Call Excel Macro That Opens All Files in a Folder

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have a Python program (shown in block 1), to open an Excel file and call a macro.

The Excel macro (shown in block 2), opens all Excel files in a specific folder.

The Python program opens Excel files and calls macros, I've tested it with different files, but when I try this Excel file, it opens but the macro doesn't run.

***Here is the Python***

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("K:\\updatebloomberg.xlsm")
xl.Visible = True
wb.Application.Run("'updatebloomberg.xlsm'!Module1.runfiles()")
wb.Close(True)
```

**and here is the VBA**

```vb
Sub runfiles()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim c As Range

  myPath = "K:\Bloomberg Data\"

  myExtension = "*.xlsx"

  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

  Do While myFile <> ""
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

Application.OnTime (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")), "refreshSheet"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

why on eartth would you do this????

```
import glob

for fnam in glob.glob("K:\Bloomberg Data\*.xlsx"):
    os.startfile(fname)
```

if that doesnt work have you checked that your network drive ((K i assume is a network drive) doesnt have an X over it when you look in file explorer)

Comment: It's worth noting that `os.startfile` uses the default program set up on your computer (that's usually the case with excel files, but not always the case with other file types like csv, etc.)  For that, you can use `subprocess` to specify the excel executable to open the files with.

Comment: Ha. Fair question - I did it basically because I had a macro that did almost everything I wanted (more stuff happens to all the files later in the macro) and I'm new to python. Clearly better ways.